# Understand API limitations with web services for a day

Tags: rest-api, api, webservices, limits

I develop an Apex REST Web Service to update contacts from an external system.

I would like to understand how many API calls the external system can do with the interface user (it will be all the time the same user who is an administrator system user with a Salesforce licence).

When I read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm#:%7E:text=For%20an%20Enterprise%20Edition%20org,until%205%3A00%20AM%20Thursday.), it means 1 000 API calls a day for an user with a Salesforce licence?

When I go in the "System Overview" page in Salesforce, I can read 5 000 000 for the last 24 hours:
[image]

What are the real limits for web services?

What is the difference between the documentation and the "System Overview" page?

The Salesforce organization is an enterprise edition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API limit *per user*. The limit is *per org*, and calculated based on how many licenses you have purchased. The limits are outlined in [API Request Limits and Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm). Note that you're apparently checking your Sandbox, which always has a flat limit of 5,000,000 API calls per day, no matter what your org has.

Your org actually has 100,000 calls per day, plus 1,000 more for each Salesforce license (so, even a one-license org has a minimum of 101,000), as well as more API calls or other license types you may have purchased. Generally speaking, this is plenty for most organizations, but if you're running out daily, you can also buy additional daily allocations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right, I understand better how it works.